# Reading email headers in Perl

Tags: email, perl, headers

I have an email account (user@domain.com) and an alias (alias@domain.com) pointing to the account.
An email sent to alias@domain.com is delivered to user@domain.com as expected.

Email headers in MS Outlook show the "To" address as alias@domain.com.
However, when the mail is fetched via a Perl script, the contents of the mail show the "To" address as user@domain.com, with no occurrence of the alias address at all.

I would like to get the original "To" address (the alias, in this scenario) via the Perl script. How should I go about this?

This is the perl script:

```
use Mail::POP3Client;
my $pop3 = new Mail::POP3Client(
USER => 'user@domain.com',
PASSWORD => 'password',
HOST => 'mail.domain.com'
);
die 'Connection failed: ' . $pop3->Message() . "\n" if $pop3->Count() == -1;
print "Most recent message: \n" . $pop3->Retrieve($pop3->Count()) . "\n";
$pop3->Close();
```

Comment: This is about interpretation of the mail header. One need to know the header of the specific mail for this and not how you access the mail server.

Comment: You need to access the headers using ` $pop3->Head(mesage_number)`.

Comment: I am looking at the headers and that information is not in the headers. The mail server is MS Exchange so my guess is that due to some config it passes on that info to Outlook, but perhaps not to other clients. But that's just a guess, I don't see why outlook would have that alias (the original To address) but a different client does not have it as any of the mail headers.